# How to validate a form in php?

Tags: php, forms

I know how to validate a form in JavaScript, but not in php.
Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Cafeteria Ordering System</title>
<style type="text/css">
@import "cafeteriastyle.css";
</style>
</head>

<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit']))
{
    //2nd page
}
else
{
?>
<form name="form1" method="post">
<table width="500" border="0" align="center" class="TableBorder">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center" class="TableTitle TableHeadingFill">Cafeteria Ordering System</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="250" align="right"><p>Customer ID</p></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="txtID"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right"><p>Num. Of Items Order</p></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="txtItems"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="btnSubmit"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a form call "form1", inside the form1, I have 2 textfield. 
When the Submit button is clicked, I want to perform a form validation check, to make sure the both textfield is filled, and jump to the 2nd page. If textfield is empty, display a alert message and stay on the same page.
I know how to do it with JavaScript, for example:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function formValidation()
    {
        if(form1.elements["Name"].value.trim() == "")
        {
            alert("Please enter the name");
            form1.elements["Name"].select();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

and just need to add `onSubmit="return formValidation"` into the form tag like:
`<form name="form1" method="post" onSubmit="return formValidation()">` then it will working probably. But how to do that with php instead of JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit']))
{
    $txnid=trim($_POST['txtID']);
    $txtItems=trim($_POST['txtItems']);
    if(!empty($txnid) && !empty($txtItems))
    {
       //2nd page
    }
    else
    {
       echo 'Both Fields are Required.';
    }

}
else
{
?>
<form name="form1" method="post">
<table width="500" border="0" align="center" class="TableBorder">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center" class="TableTitle TableHeadingFill">Cafeteria Ordering System</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="250" align="right"><p>Customer ID</p></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="txtID"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right"><p>Num. Of Items Order</p></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="txtItems"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="btnSubmit"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: how to let it stay on same page if field is not filled up? `window.history.back()` and `location="index.php"` woking well but I want to know is there any way better than these?

Comment: it comes o else condition then it just show message not to redirect on second page it come there if it come in if condition in this we check for i is filled or not

Answer (score 1):

Use zebra form http://stefangabos.ro/php-libraries/zebra-form/ 
it is the best 
will do both php and js validation

Comment: It's a way, but nothings says it's the best

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld  sorry! but for me its best

Answer (score 1):

Use this check with jquery  it might be help you

```
 function formValidation()
    {
        if($("input[name='name']").trim() == "")
        {
            alert("Please enter the name");
            $("input[name='name']").focus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
function formValidation()
    {
        if($("input[name='name']").val().trim() == "")
        {
            alert("Please Enter The Name");

            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```